# A tough double integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, probability-distributions

I am looking at an ugly ratio of two random variables and am interested in the density of the the ratio. So what I did was to write down the joint characteristic function of the numerator and denominator and now try to invert it. But it sounds like a really hard  task.

Define  $$g(u,v)=\Big(\cosh \beta + \frac{c+u}{\beta}\sinh \beta \Big)^{-\frac12}$$  where $$\beta=\sqrt{c^2+2cu+2v}$$
Now how should I approach $$\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}e^{vs+u\alpha}g(u,v)dudv=?$$

I will be happy with a sum, double sum or anything like that. I know that $\alpha,c>0$. I appreciate your help.